# Pokemon trading between two gen II games on the GBA SP

Tags: game-boy-advance, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I know you can't trade between pokemon games Gen II and Gen III.

But can I play a Gen II game (for example Pokemon Crystal) on my GameBoy Advance SP and play another Gen II game (for example Pokemon Gold) on my GameBoy Color and trade between those two games?

If yes, what type of linking cables and/or adapters do I need?

Answer (score 2):

From what I found, you can use a Game Boy Color Game Link Cable to do this. The GBA SP port accept this cable, enabling retro compatibility on old GBC games.

You can find more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Link_Cable)